# C - most members in a stack implemented with array

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I'm trying to write a function that will print out a value of when the stack had most members.

Example: push(1), push(2), push(3), push(4), push(5), push(6)
Maximum members should be 6.

Example 2: push(1), push(2), push(3), push(4), push(5), push(6), pop, pop, push(5), push(6), push(7), push(8), pop;
Maximum members should be 8.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this.
I started by adding a counter everytime push, or pop function is called.

```
case 2:
            pushCalled++;
            scanf("%d", &val);
            ret_val = push(stack, &top, val);
            if(ret_val==-1) DEBUG("Stog is full.\n");
            break;

case 3:
            popCalled++;
            ret_val = pop(stack, &top);
            if(ret_val==-1) DEBUG("Stog is empty.\n");
            break;
```

And sending the data over to the function:

```
case 1:
            TopTopova(top, pushCalled, popCalled);
            break;
```

In the function itself, my thought process was to check if the pop was not called even once, because that would mean that the maximum would be = pushCalled;

```
   void TopTopova(int top, int pushOperation, int popOpeartion)
{
    if(popOpeartion == 0)
    {
        max = pushOperation;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I'm not sure how to keep track of the maximum when we also use pop. I hope my problem is clear enough for you guys to understand.

Comment: Instead of `pushCalled` and `popCalled` how about a single var called `stackSize`? Increment when pushing, decrement when popping.

Comment: Instead of (or additionally to) `popCalled` and `pushCalled` add a Counter for the current stack size if you don't have it already. Then add a member `maxStackSize`, initialize it with zero and detect the Maximum of currentStackSize: `maxStackSize=max(maxStackSize, currenStackSize)` when you do `++pushCalled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define some `currentDepth` to increment when push is called and decrement when pop. Also define `maxDepth` (a value of when the stack had most members) and check if `currentDepth` is greater than max depth.

```
int maxDepth = 0;
int currentDepth= 0;
switch(action) {
        case 2:
                    currentDepth++;
                    scanf("%d", &val);
                    ret_val = push(stack, &top, val);
                    if(ret_val==-1) DEBUG("Stog is full.\n");
                    break;

        case 3:
                    currentDepth--;
                    ret_val = pop(stack, &top);
                    if(ret_val==-1) DEBUG("Stog is empty.\n");
                    break; 
}

if (currentDepth > maxDepth)
{
    maxDepth = currentDepth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep two variables - `int size`, to keep the current size of the stack, and `int max_size` to hold the information you want.

`size` would increment when pushing and decrements when "*poping*". `max_size`would change only in the end of `push` procedure, like this:

```
if (size > max_size)
    max_size = size;
```

Comment: Size is a misnomer in this context.  The number of elements in the stack is commonly referred to as stack depth.  It's size is dependent on its depth and the size of the elements in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a track of the current maximum and do something like this in your `push` function:

```
int
push(stack* this, item_t item)
{
    // Push the element
    this->most = max(this->most, this->size);
    // Do things and return
}
```

The `pop` operation won't affect it at all.

Comment: @harper was faster than me.